Youtube website is hardly loading and videos aren't playing
It seems to initiate downloading and streaming the video but the download seems hardly working and then stops. Also the fan seems to work at high speed.
This is under firefox 27.0 (64-Bit), but I experience the same issue in Chromium.
It's a Intel NUC: Intel® Core™ i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8
Graphics: Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics 655 (CFL GT3)
nuc@nuc:~$ ffplay
ffplay version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers

nuc@nuc:~$ mpv
mpv v0.38.0-dirty Copyright © 2000-2024 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on Jun  8 2024 07:59:48
libplacebo version: v6.338.2
FFmpeg version: 7.0.1
FFmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       59.8.100
   libavcodec      61.3.100
   libavformat     61.1.100
   libswscale      8.1.100
   libavfilter     10.1.100
   libswresample   5.1.100

nuc@nuc:~$ ffplay https://youtu.be/MQxlE0ICumI
ffplay version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-libsmbclient
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
https://youtu.be/MQxlE0ICumI: Invalid data found when processing input
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0  



 nuc@nuc:~$ mpv https://youtu.be/MQxlE0ICumI
     (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1920x1080 30.000fps)
     (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (opus 2ch 48000Hz)
    File tags:
     Uploader: Stack Overflow
     Channel_URL: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2hxYQtGLEkcOMK4h8JRycA
    Using hardware decoding (vaapi).
    AO: [pulse] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
    VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 vaapi[nv12]
    [ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: root atom offset 0x13211b: partial file
    [ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: root atom offset 0x13211b: partial file
    (...) AV: 00:01:45 / 00:13:50 (13%) A-V:  0.000 Cache: 0.0s
    Exiting... (Quit)

nuc@nuc:~$ mpv --demuxer-lavf-format=mpegts --vd-lavc-software-fallback=yes
mpv v0.38.0-dirty Copyright © 2000-2024 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on Jun  8 2024 07:59:48
libplacebo version: v6.338.2
FFmpeg version: 7.0.1
FFmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       59.8.100
   libavcodec      61.3.100
   libavformat     61.1.100
   libswscale      8.1.100
   libavfilter     10.1.100
   libswresample   5.1.100

Usage:   mpv [options] [url|path/]filename

Basic options:
 --start=<time>    seek to given (percent, seconds, or hh:mm:ss) position
 --no-audio        do not play sound
 --no-video        do not play video
 --fs              fullscreen playback
 --sub-file=<file> specify subtitle file to use
 --playlist=<file> specify playlist file

 --list-options    list all mpv options
 --h=<string>      print options which contain the given string in their name


What are the system specs? Do you have NVidia graphics?

It's a Intel NUC: Intel® Core™ i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8, Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics 655 (CFL GT3)

Have you checked mpv or ffplay from the terminal?

Does other pages work ok ? Without or with media?

Yes they do. Probably apart from video-heavy websites.

@JayCravens: I have installed mpv, ffplay was installed already. See above.

Does playback still lag and kick the fan speed up?  Try:  mpv https://youtu.be/MQxlE0ICumI or ffplay https://youtu.be/MQxlE0ICumI

@JayCravens Yes, see above.

Yup, same here, but mpv works. Imgur

@JayCravens: See above for mpv.

@JayCravens : What shall I do with these commands?

Add the URL at the end.

@JayCravens Which URL?

Any URL.  See where the mpv output said Usage:   mpv [options] [url|path/]filename] It output the help because there was no source after the options.

@JayCravens Please provide a full command.

As far as "full command", that's relative to the situation. Which is why I mentioned a few options that pertain to your configuration.If you run mpv --list-options you will see over 1000 options you can use to make it play properly.
The output suggests you have an offset issue:
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: root atom offset 0x13211b: partial file

Knowing this, my first course of action was:
mpv --list-options | grep offset

fedora@/dev/pts/1:$ mpv --list-options | grep offset
 --dvbin-channel-switch-offset    Integer (default: 0)
 --hr-seek-demuxer-offset         Float (default: 0)
 --osd-shadow-offset              Float (default: 0)
 --sub-shadow-offset              Float (default: 0)
 --video-timing-offset            Double (0 to 1) (default: 0.05)

--hr-seek-demuxer-offset and --video-timing-offset are the two that would apply so I started there.  Float means the value is a floating point.

A floating point number, is a positive or negative whole number with a decimal point. Floating point numbers get their name from the way the decimal point can "float" to any position necessary. Due to this, in computer science, floating point numbers are often referred to as floats.

What I always do to quickly test the option is try 1.  Then go backwards, 0.7 to 0.3, and by then you should see an effect of some kind.  If not, on to the next option.  If the option is not self explanatory...
(like --vd-lavc-software-fallback=yes and --gpu-sw=yes are obviously use hw decoding and fallback to sw or sw only)
...now is when I'm pulling up the documentation.
--hr-seek=<no|absolute|yes|default>
Select when to use precise seeks that are not limited to keyframes. Such
seeks require decoding video from the previous keyframe up to the target
position and so can take some time depending on decoding performance. For
some video formats, precise seeks are disabled. This option selects the
default choice to use for seeks; it is possible to explicitly override that
default in the definition of key bindings and in input commands.

:no:       Never use precise seeks.
:absolute: Use precise seeks if the seek is to an absolute position in the
           file, such as a chapter seek, but not for relative seeks like
           the default behavior of arrow keys.
:default:  Like ``absolute``, but enable hr-seeks in audio-only cases. The
           exact behavior is implementation specific and may change with
           new releases (default).
:yes:      Use precise seeks whenever possible.
:always:   Same as ``yes`` (for compatibility).

--hr-seek-demuxer-offset=<seconds>
This option exists to work around failures to do precise seeks (as in
``--hr-seek``) caused by bugs or limitations in the demuxers for some file
formats. Some demuxers fail to seek to a keyframe before the given target
position, going to a later position instead. The value of this option is
subtracted from the time stamp given to the demuxer. Thus, if you set this
option to 1.5 and try to do a precise seek to 60 seconds, the demuxer is
told to seek to time 58.5, which hopefully reduces the chance that it
erroneously goes to some time later than 60 seconds. The downside of
setting this option is that precise seeks become slower, as video between
the earlier demuxer position and the real target may be unnecessarily
decoded.

Based on this information the next command I'd try would be:
mpv --vd-lavc-software-fallback=yes --hr-seek=absolute https://youtu.be/MQxlE0ICumI


Much over my head, maybe I can wait for 24.04 LTS?
